# Packaging C++ library into a Rails application for Heroku use

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, heroku

asked the next thing from Heroku support the other day:

> I have an app that will
>   require a client library written in
>   C++. I
>   have doubts can that be done with
>   Heroku. Is it possible at all, any
>   alternatives how can a C++ library be
>   installed and used by an app with
>   Heroku?

And I got the next answer:

> We currently don't have a good way to
>   do this. You'll need to figure out how
>   to package into your app and compile
>   static x64 binaries into the repo.

I haven't done that before. Does anyone have any good pointers how package a C++ library into a Rails app so it can be used with Heroku?

Thanks.

Comment: I've merged your unregistered account into your registered account. You can now edit this question and leave comments under answers. I converted your latest answer into a comment for you.

Comment: You can wrap a C++ library in Ruby using Rb++. See my answer below. My interpretation of the above answer from Heroku support is that you can build and statically link the C++ library, then build and statically link the Ruby extension with that library, then include the extension in your project and you're good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To wrap the C++ library in Ruby, you want [Rb++](https://github.com/jameskilton/rbplusplus).

Alternately, you can wrap the C++ library in C and then wrap that with [Ruby-FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi).

I'm not sure what, if anything, one can do to get the native extensions compiled on Heroku. I'd contact their support and ask.

Comment: I believe Heroku uses Bundler to install gems, which means that the gems' installation scripts should get run just like they do anywhere else. I seem to recall using gems with native extensions on Heroku without incident.

Rb++ looks very useful; I hadn't heard of it. [RubyInline](http://www.zenspider.com/ZSS/Products/RubyInline/) might possibly come in handy too.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't done this either, but my guess would be that you could write a wrapper gem around it, and make the C++ library be a native extension in the gem.

Comment: Interesting. I guess it might be a good opportunity to create a gem. Somehow this requirement is not a high priority but I will try your suggestion when it comes back. Thanks Marnen.